# mathematica, picking our linear terms from an equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

so I'm trying to pick out the linear terms in an expression - for example if I say

> eqn = dy/dt + y == y^2

, dy/dt+y is linear and y^2 is non linear.

I know in this case I can just use 
eqn[[1]] to pull out the lhs and have that be my linear terms, but is there some way I can use a string pattern or something to get the linear parts of any entered equation?

Comment: you know `dy/dt` is just a fraction and does not depend on `y` at all. If you had a differential equation that would change the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some quick solution I came up with. You may need to change this for your purposes, but maybe it is a possibility. First the terms are converted into a string. This is then searched for "+" or "-" and separated. The individual terms are tested for linearity.

```
terms = y + y^2 - Sqrt[y];
string = ToString[terms, InputForm];
split = StringSplit[string, {"+", "-"}];

Do[
 (*Take term i and convert the string to an expression*)

 exp = ToExpression[split[[i]]];
 Print[exp];

 (*Test for Additivity: f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)*)

 pexp = exp /. {y -> y + c};(*f(x+y)*)
 cexp = exp /. {y -> c};(*f(y)*)
 test1 = pexp - (exp + cexp) // Simplify;(*f(x+y)-(f(x)+f(y))*)

 (*Test for Homogeneity: f(a*x) = a*f(x)*)

 aexp = exp /. {y -> a*y};(*f(a*x)*)
 test2 = a*exp - aexp // Simplify;(*a*f(x)-f(a*x)*)

 If[test1 == 0 && test2 == 0,
  Print["linear"]]
 , {i, 1, Length[split]}]
```